# How to use SREP with Freearc?

Tags: linux

I've read the instructions at http://freearc.org/research/SREP.aspx and added SREP to my arc.ini but I can't find SREP in the gui? How can I compress my files with SREP? I've also downloaded the archive for SREP but I can't find any information where to put the files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> You should install latest (Feb 2012) FreeArc and replace `arc.ini`
>   with the attached one. 
>   Then use FreeArc GUI and select max. compression mode and enable checkboxes
>   for srep/precomp compression. 
>   First line in the dialog will show you cmdline options
>   that you need. 
>   Decompression may be performed by `unarc.exe` and require `arc.ini`
>   and `srep`/`precomp` executables. 
>   It was about using `precomp`/`srep` inside arc archives.
>
> You can also use them "outside" i.e. archive files w/o compression (`tar`/`7z -mx0`/`arc -m0 -dm0`), then process this archive with `precomp` and/or `srep`
>   and then compress output with `7z -mx` / `arc -mx`.

                — Copied from
                [Bulat Ziganshin's post](https://encode.su/threads/43-FreeArc/page81)
                to
                [Encode's Forum](https://encode.su/forum.php)
                ,
                which includes an attached "arcini.zip" file

Note that the above post was made April 15th, 2012. 
[Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/FreeArc) says

- FreeArc was developed by Bulat Ziganshin (author of the post quoted above).
- The last releast of FreeArc was beta version 0.666, released May 20, 2010.
        *So where is one to get the Feb 2012 release?*
- A "FreeArc Next" version is under development,
  with version FA 0.11 released in October 2016.

The top Google search result for FreeArc is the [FreeArc download site
at SourceForge.net](https://sourceforge.net/projects/freearc/), but Wikipedia says that this is abandoned. 
It seems that the Wikipedia page is not being effectively maintained,
as it still links to the (now defunct) encode.ru site.

Comment: Gigamegs: (1) If you are Bulat Ziganshin, you must disclose that you are talking about your software project.  If you are not Bulat Ziganshin, you must disclose when you are copying somebody else’s post.   (2) Since Bulat Ziganshin’s post refers to “the attached one”, it would have been helpful if you had pointed out that his post has an attached file.

Comment: Hey mate, I did 2) the post contains a link!!!

Comment: Yes, you dropped a link after two paragraphs that, at first glance, appear to be a self-contained (albeit brief) answer. You didn’t say, “The above is incomplete; you need to go to this link to get the file mentioned in the first paragraph.” It’s not clear enough.